# Route is not defined signed route laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having weird problem with signed routes, lets say i have the following in my web.php

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
```

Running this works:

```
URL::to(route('index'))
// "https://app.test"
```

but running this does not:

```
URL::signedRoute(route('index'))
//InvalidArgumentException with message 'Route [https://app.test] not defined.'
```

I've also tried

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('index')->middleware('signed');
```

And the same error occurs?

Is anyone able to point in the right direction as to why this is happening? I'm using Laravel Valet if anyone is able to replicate. I have the Signed middleware in my Kernel.php file too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this** without `route` word in the signedRoute:

```
URL::signedRoute('index');
```